# part of the store relies on some other part

Tags: redux

As a scenario, the user can click a button to create a list of timestamps that shows the corresponding times when the clicks are made. User can also click on an item on the list to remove an item.

In terms of the store, there's a counter state that keeps track of how many times the button has been clicked, and then there's another state that keeps track of a list of timestamps. And each item on list state has an id field that derive from the counter state. So one part of the store depends on another part.

As an attempt, I dispatch one action, and both reducers handle the same action, and it works fine, but only that it's not DRY. Before dispatching, I have to add 1 to the counter state in order to get the new id which I use as the action payload, after dispatching, I add 1 to the counter state again to return the new counter state. That's repeating myself.

What's the general standard way of handling a problem of this nature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general simple way is to use thunks. You need to setup a middleware, check out the docs:
https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

This allows you to dispatch a function instead of a simple action. Within that function, you can access state and dispatch as many times as you want.

In your scenario, you would first increment the counter, then retrieve the length to get your new id, and then dispatch another action to create a timestamp.

Some imaginary code for your action creators:

```
// basic action creators to be handled in your reducers
function incrementCounter(){
   return { type: 'INCREMENT'}
}
function createTimestamp(id){
   return { type: 'CREATE_TS', id }
}
// this is the thunk
function incrementAndTimestamp(){
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
     // increment the counter
     dispatch(incrementCounter())
     // generate an "id" from the resulting state
     const newId = getState().counter.length
     // and use that id to further update your state
     dispatch(createTimestamp(newId))
   }
}
```

You will need to handle those 2 different actions in your reducers and you have now two separate pieces of code. The thunk is the glue that dispatches, gets the data from one part, and uses it to affect the other part.

Comment: how's that different from dispatching 2 actions from the component without using thunk?

Comment: The difference is of course encapsulation: your component doesn't need to know what happens under the hood when it wants to do his stuff. It's way easier to test the component and the action creators in isolation. This is the general solution to your problem, but different scenarios may require little tweaks here and there. :)